# R: automatically generate dataframes from single function

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a collection of ten dataframes (df.a, df.b, and so on) and the following concept in R

```
df.x.new = df.x %>% do this %>% do that...
```

I wondered if there is an elegant way to interchange the df.x variable of my single code line above iteratively with my dfs one by another, to get ten new dfs as an output.

Meaning something like this:

```
#place your elegant code here

df.a.new = df.a %>% do this %>% do that
df.b.new = df.b % do this %>% do that

#and so on
```

Edit:

```
#this should serve as a minimal reproducible code
df.a = c(1,2,3)
df.b = c(4,5,6)
df.c = c(7,8,9)

df.a.new = df.a %>% left_join(df.b)
```

Comment: If you can provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code, sample data, and what you've tried, you will likely get a better response. However, sounds like you just want a function, `example_function <- function(df) df %>% ...`

Comment: You can add your 10 dos to a list and then pass that list to `lapply()` and get a list back with your 10 new data frames.

Comment: [List of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227), along Dave2e's comment.

Comment: @caldwellst is it better now?

Comment: @Dave2e yes, I was thinking about something like that, but does not know how to use lapply() in my case

Comment: Perhaps something like this? `names(.GlobalEnv)[grepl('df.', names(.GlobalEnv))] |> lapply(function(x) get(x) |> max())`